# js find Elements with same innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, innerhtml

I have a button that has some text and I get that text by innerHTML

```
var helpName = helpButton.parentElement.querySelector('span').innerHTML;
```

Then I have a few other buttons that trigger accordion boxes

```
var helpAccordions = modal.getElementsByClassName('accordion');
```

I would like to select one element from helpAccordions that matches helpName and set it as a var.

```
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <h3 class="modal-title">Help</h3>

        <button class="accordion">Key Partners</button>
    </div>

    <div class="section-header">
        <span>Key Partners</span>
        <div class="help-icon"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you please provide your HTML?

Comment: done, I am still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use jQuery, I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u7td3b8s/1/) showing it working, below is the relevant code.

```
var helpName = helpButton.parentElement.querySelector('span').innerHTML;
var helpAccordions = modal.getElementsByClassName('accordion');
var length = helpAccordions.length;

var myButton;
for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var button = helpAccordions[i];
    if(button.innerHTML === helpName) {
        myButton = button;
        break;
    }
}
console.log(myButton) // the button with Key Partners as the text
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use with jquery [`contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
$('button').click(function(){
var a = $('span:Contains('+$(this).text()+')').parent();
//result varible is a
console.log(a.attr('class'))
})

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <h3 class="modal-title">Help</h3>

        <button class="accordion">Key Partners</button>
    </div>

    <div class="section-header">
        <span>Key Partners</span>
        <div class="help-icon"></div>
    </div>
```